# enzyme test, context not rendering elements

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am using enzyme to write my tests, before adding a context to my component which is the `consumer component` in this case, the snapshot rendered is not showing any elements and every time i add a `dive()` or `shallow()` I got the same error
how can i access the elements while using context

```js
const wrapper = shallow(
    <MyComponent {...initialProps} store={mockStore(initialState)} />,
    {context},
  );

  const contents = wrapper
    .dive() // dive in connect
    .dive() // dive in withLogss
    .dive() // dive in Motion
    .find("MyComponent")
    .dive(); // dive in Host

  expect(contents.context()).toEqual({myBoolean: true});

  it("should render properly", () => {
    expect(contents).toMatchSnapshot();
  });


Result: 

<ContextConsumer>
  <Component />
</ContextConsumer>
```

Comment: You are using shallow render, try to use mount instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Enzyme` prior to `v3.10.0` [lacked support of React's new Context API](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1908).

From the [`v3.10.0` Changelog](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#3100):

> shallow: Support rendering and dive()ing createContext() providers and consumers (#1966)

Make sure you are using `enzyme` `v3.10.0` or later **and** `enzyme-adapter-react-16` `v1.15.1` or later.